# Function is not returning values when called from outside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-defined-functions

I am calling the function and `a` does not keep the value i.e. `mob_f` `return`ed from the function below:

`a = get_mobile()`

The function is:

```
def get_mobile():
    ws = sheet_select()
    mobile = []
    mob_i = []
    mob_f = []
    mob_j = []

    for col in ws.iter_cols():
        for cell in col:
            if cell.value == 'Mobile':
                x=column_index_from_string(cell.column)
                for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col = x, min_row = 2, max_col = x):
                    for cell in row:
                        if cell.value != None:
                            mobile.append(cell.value)
    for i in mobile:
        h = i
        h = h.replace(" ", "")
        h = h.replace("+(91)-", ",")
        h = h.replace("+91", "")
        h = h.replace("-", "")
        mob_i.append(h)

    for i in mob_i:
        h = i
        h = h.split(',')
        mob_j.append(h)
    mob_x = [item for sublist in mob_j for item in sublist]
    for i in mob_x:
        if i != '':
            h = i
            return mob_f.append(h)
```

If I use the code without defining it as a `function`, it runs without a problem and I get `mob_f`.

I assumed the problem was `return` placed incorrectly. I tried a lot of combinations and keep failing. Also last night this same function was working, I can't understand where I went wrong.

Comment: Can you include the excel file?

Comment: @MYGz, the excel file open etc is running smoothly. I would include it if you think it is required.

Comment: Yeap. Include it if you can. It gives a better understanding.

Comment: @MyGz Maurice's answer below sorted me out. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok. Np. It's better to include input and output along with code to get better suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append returns nothing, i think you want this:

```
...
for i in mob_x:
    if i != '':
        h = i
        mob_f.append(h)
return mob_f
```

Comment: Thanks. This fixed everything. I read the docs and somehow got the impression that if the `return` doesn't have a evaluating expression it won't return.